# JAXB, public fields mapping behavior differs from private fields with @XmlElement annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Should @XmlElement annotation force the mapping of a field as it was a public field?

That is, the field:

```
public HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

get mapped ok.
Regardless the things that are said around the web about mapping `Map`s, when 
i Marshall my class this produces a nice:

```
<myMap>
    <entry>
        <key>cat</key> <value>meows</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>dog</key> <value>barks</value>
    </entry>
</myMap>
```

but if i add a second *identical* field, but for the fact that is private and so, in order to be mapped, annotated with `@XmlElement`:

```
@XmlElement
private HashMap<String, String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

it doesn't work any more, that is it produces an empty element:

```
<myMap2/>
```

**So @XmlElement doesn't just "turn on" mapping**. Well, it does for simple type fields, even for Lists but NOT for Maps.

The question is: is it a wrong (naive) interpretation of the @XmlElement? Is there a way to accomplish just what JAXB already does for public Map fields **without** developing adapters?

This should be enough, just in case I've pasted the complete, yet minimal, source code here:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class K {

    public HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @XmlElement
    private HashMap<String, String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //An Array list that yet gets correctly mapped
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main (String [] args) throws JAXBException {

    K k = new K();

    k.myMap.put("dog", "barks");
    k.myMap.put("cat", "meows");

    k.myMap2.put("bird", "tweets");
    k.myMap2.put("snake", "rattles");

    k.myList.add("first");
    k.myList.add("second");

    k.save();

}

public void save() throws JAXBException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(K.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    marshaller.marshal(this, new File("K.xml"));

}
}
```

The XML produced, i've added empty lines around  to show it.

```
<k>
<myMap>
    <entry>
        <key>cat</key>
        <value>meows</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>dog</key>
        <value>barks</value>

   </entry>
</myMap>


<myMap2/>


<myList>first</myList>
<myList>second</myList>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Your interpretation of the JAXB spec is correct.  I have confirmed the bug you are seeing with the JAXB implementation included in JDK 1.7.0_21 for the Mac.  Could you enter an issue using the following link:

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

If you use EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB provider (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) then you get the correct output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k>
   <myMap>
      <entry>
         <key>cat</key>
         <value>meows</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>dog</key>
         <value>barks</value>
      </entry>
   </myMap>
   <myMap2>
      <entry>
         <key>bird</key>
         <value>tweets</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>snake</key>
         <value>rattles</value>
      </entry>
   </myMap2>
   <myList>first</myList>
   <myList>second</myList>
</k>
```